# com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) sample working without success

I installed and initialized the client:

```
export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"

echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update \
    && sudo apt-get -y install google-cloud-sdk \
    && sudo apt-get -y install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java \
    && sudo apt-get -y install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python \

gcloud init
```

Then I authenticated successfully:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account 13672300789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=DockerStorage-e7def0adcafb.json
```

Then I tried the quick start sample:

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
String bucketName = "my-first-bucket";  // "my-new-bucket";
Bucket bucket = storage.create(BucketInfo.of(bucketName));
System.out.printf("Bucket %s created.%n", bucket.getName());
```

BOOM unauthorized

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: 401 Unauthorized
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Are you running this on a local machine or on a GCE or AppEngine instance?

Comment: tried on local and vm

Comment: On a GCE instance, you shouldn't even need to run gcloud auth. The program should be able to authorize as the GCE's associated service account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hrm...good question. Theoretically this should work  If you don't otherwise specify auth, that library will first attempt to use the credentials file specified by the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, and if that's not set, [it should go looking for your gcloud credentials](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/0d9d1b3ce548aa5335e23b8c2ec0464df8002d9f/google-cloud-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/ServiceOptions.java#L370).

I'm guessing that it can't find your gcloud credentials for some reason. By default, they'll be in the ".config/gcloud" directory under your home directory, but that can be overridden. Maybe check to see if there're some files there?

One thing worth trying is simply copying a service account's JSON file to that machine and specifying the path to it with the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. That shouldn't be necessary, but if that fails as well, something more interesting is going on.

Comment: I had to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in my ~/.profile and restart my machine.

Answer (score 4):

At first, You have to a generate a Service account credential.

**Generating a service account credential**
To generate a private key in JSON or PKCS12 format:

1. Open the list of credentials in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
   [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=3&_ga=2.252090441.-1710739843.1518428918)
2. Click Create credentials.
3. Select Service account key.
4. A Create service account key window opens.
5. Click the drop-down box below Service account, then click New service account.
6. Enter a name for the service account in Name.
7. Use the default Service account ID or generate a different one.
8. Select the Key type: JSON or P12.
9. Click Create.

Then simply use the credential json file in you code.

```
    StorageOptions storageOptions = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
       .setProjectId("YOUR_PROJECT_ID")
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new 
         FileInputStream("path/YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CRENDENTIAL.json"))).build();
    Storage storage = storageOptions.getService();
```